# Get the all thumbnail_url from the header images

Tags: wordpress, header

I have got the array using the "get_uploaded_header_images()" function. Now i want print all the thumbnail_url images in another array.

The array i have got is

```
          Array
(
    [cropped-abstract-white-awesome-album-black-colorful-cool-music-nice-1064669.jpg] => Array
        (
            [attachment_id] => 23
            [url] => http://localhost/TantraProjects/gradualis/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cropped-abstract-white-awesome-album-black-colorful-cool-music-nice-1064669.jpg
            [thumbnail_url] => http://localhost/TantraProjects/gradualis/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cropped-abstract-white-awesome-album-black-colorful-cool-music-nice-1064669.jpg
            [width] => 1300
            [height] => 400
        )

    [cropped-color.jpg] => Array
        (
            [attachment_id] => 24
            [url] => http://localhost/TantraProjects/gradualis/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cropped-color.jpg
            [thumbnail_url] => http://localhost/TantraProjects/gradualis/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cropped-color.jpg
            [width] => 1300
            [height] => 400
        )

)
```

Now i want the array of all the [thumbnail_url].

Comment: Please explain little more...

Comment: I have got the answer. I use it through plain php foreach function for it. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Ok No Problem...Enjoy Coding...